# Using SVD on each matrix in a list

Tags: r, svd

I'm trying to use the svd() function on all matrices within a list. Currently, the results only appear for the first matrix in the list. How can this be done for every matrix in the list?

```
svd_list <- function(data) {

    for (i in 1:length(data)) {

    svd <- svd(data[[i]])

    return(svd$d) 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over writing the results in `svd` in each iteration. Initialise an empty list to store the results.

```
svd_list <- function(data) {
  svd <- vector('list', length(data))
  for (i in 1:length(data)) {
    svd[[i]] <- svd(data[[i]])$d
  }
  return(svd)
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `lapply` :

```
svd_list <- function(data) {
  lapply(data, function(x) svd(x)$d)
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting the following message: "Error in svd(x) : infinite or missing values in 'x'" - any thoughts?

Comment: It would be difficult to debug this without data but I think error message is quite clear that you have missing values (`NA`) in your matrix. How do you want to deal with those? Maybe you can consider them as 0 and do `lapply(data, function(x) svd(replace(x, is.na(x), 0))$d)`